Unwanted Parameter in Wordpress Site Page Url
Just found out some pages in GSC that contain parameter like this
https://druhomes.com/category/tips-ideas/page/30/?q=/category/tips-ideas/page/10/index.html
I want to redirect it to the page, where actually it has canonical to this page but Google keep indexing it
https://druhomes.com/category/tips-ideas/page/30/
I have no idea where it is come from. I am using a wordpress here. Is there anyone facing problem like this?


This is a category page so there is no need to index category and tag pages because they will not be your target pages in Google search for ranking.
The category and tag pages are not rich with content, media, links and headings so they can't be ranked in Google SERPs without these things.
I have seen you're using Yoast on your site so simply follow these steps.
Yoast SEO > Settings > Categories > Turn off (Show categories in search results)

Follow the screenshot for reference. https://imgur.com/a/6yb2bzk
After doing the above action, the problem in your Search Console will be automatically resolved. Just click on "Validate Fix" and wait for a few days.
